# How to deploy EJB 3.0 using Command Line?

Tags: java, command-line, jboss, ejb, wildfly

I am following [this](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2071724/ejb-fundamentals-and-session-beans.html?page=3) fundamentals of JEE tutorial which provides instruction to create a minimal EJB deployment.

I have gone through the steps in the tutorials but made changes to the following command line invocations

- >set CLASSPATH=.;E:\wildfly-10.1.0\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\bin\client\jboss-client.jar; **(Changed from the long list in the tutorial)**
- >jar -cvf SimpleSessionApp.ear beans*.java **(Changed file extention to .ear from .ejb3)**
- copy SimpleSessionApp.ear E:\wildfly-10.1.0\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\deployments **(Copied to the wildfly deployment directory)**

I started the server and I did not get any errors. However, I did not get set of standard names the server log outputs when a bean is deployed.

I ran the client application using the following command as in tutorial

- >java -D java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory -D java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces -D java.naming.provider.url=localhost client.SimpleSessionClient Now is the time for all good men

I get the following error as the output

> Error: Could not find or load main class java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory

I know the tutorial caters for an older version of Java and JBoss. However, I modified the old references to point to the newer environment as mentioned above. So I assume versioning is not a issue here? BTW I'm just starting to learn EJB. Any insights would be great.

**My Environment**

- Java 1.8.0.212
- Wildfly 10.1.0.Final
- Notepad

Comment: I think the issue is with classpath/missing dependency. Which jars are you using/present at classpath?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the reference documentation https://docs.wildfly.org/17/Developer_Guide.html#JNDI_Remote_Reference as it seems your are passing wrong configuration parameters.

`final Properties env = new Properties();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://localhost:8080");
// the property below is required ONLY if there is no ejb client configuration loaded (such as a
// jboss-ejb-client.properties in the class path) and the context will be used to lookup EJBs
env.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
InitialContext remoteContext = new InitialContext(env);
RemoteCalculator ejb = (RemoteCalculator) remoteContext.lookup("wildfly-http-remoting-ejb/CalculatorBean!"
                + RemoteCalculator.class.getName());`

Comment: How to invoke this in a command line. I'm running this in command line

Comment: -Djava.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory -Djava.naming.provider.url=http-remoting://localhost:8080